# How to find parent form element when element is clicked using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I click on **Order Now** button (`<a class="btn btn-lp btn-popup" data-popup-open="popup-1" href="#">Order Now</a>`) the popup appears with the form buttons that will send data to the server.

```html
<div class="section-pick-your-box section-choose-a-plan">
  <ul class="content">
    <li>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <a class="btn btn-lp btn-popup" data-popup-open="popup-1" href="#">Order Now</a>
        <div class="popup" data-popup="popup-1">
          <div class="popup-inner">
            <form action="/cart/add" method="post" novalidate enctype="multipart/form-data" data-productid="">
              <input type="hidden" name="properties[shipping_interval_frequency]" value="1">
              <input type="hidden" name="properties[shipping_interval_unit_type]" value="Months">
              <input type="hidden" name="id" value="12673316716586">
              <input type="hidden" name="properties[subscription_id]" value="106203">
              <input type="hidden" name="purchase_type" value="autodeliver">

              <div class="price-button-wrap">
                <a class="btn btn-lp buy-now" href="/cart">Wrapped</a>
              </div>
            </form>
            <form action="/cart/add" method="post" novalidate enctype="multipart/form-data" data-productid="">
              <input type="hidden" name="properties[shipping_interval_frequency]" value="1">
              <input type="hidden" name="properties[shipping_interval_unit_type]" value="Months">
              <input type="hidden" name="id" value="12673316683818">
              <input type="hidden" name="properties[subscription_id]" value="106203">
              <input type="hidden" name="purchase_type" value="autodeliver">

              <div class="price-button-wrap">
                <a class="btn btn-lp buy-now" href="/cart">Unwrapped</a>
              </div>
            </form>
            <p><a data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">Close</a></p>
            <a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">x</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The problem with the code above is that it does not recognize the parent form or closest form element from which the button was triggered.

This is my current jquery code below to get the parent form element:

```js
$('.section-pick-your-box .content > li .popup-inner > form .buy-now').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $data = $(this).closest('li').find('form').serialize();
  console.log($data);
});
```

When I `console.log`, I am getting the data of both forms.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have multiple `form`s inside an `li`, so instead of closest `li`, check for closest `form`

```
 var $data = $(this).closest('form').serialize();
```